# simple jquery dialog box can't create input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

may any one help me create a input box inside my dialog box? i am using the jquery-ui.js. this is my code:

```
 $(document).on("click",".savebtn",function().        {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");

            $.dialog({
                title: "Activation date ",
                  content:"Activation date ",                                    
               create: function() {
                  $("#inputBox").val();
                },
                  closeBack:function(){
                    $.dialog.message({
                      content: "The id is "+ id
                    });
                  },
                  buttons:[
                    {
                      text:"Click me"
                    }
                  ]
            });
    });
```

Comment: Could you give a bit of your HTML? 

Also what do you find is not working so far?

Comment: this is pretty much my HTML   <input name="inputBox" id="inputBox"  >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bonpyj2x/3/)

HTML:

```
<div id='dialog' style='display: none;'>
  <input type="text" />
</div>

<button>
  Click Me!
</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      resizable: false,
      modal: true,
      title: "My Awesome Title",
      buttons: {
        "Do Something": function() {
          alert("Do something if I was clicked.");
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          alert("Dialog Canceled");
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: That is so much cleaner than what I was mocking together in Fiddle.

Comment: just one problem. the alert box appears very small. can you please help me to resize it . make it a bit lager.

Comment: @trinidado You can set the `height` and the `width` of the dialog to fit your needs. Try something like `height: 400, width: 800`.

Comment: @trinidado Here's the updated fiddle with the `height` and `width` set to a certain value [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bonpyj2x/4/).